# Split function in hive does not seem to be working on caret symbol

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

The data in my column `user_likes` is as follows: anime^sitcom^scifi. I am trying to get the first item in the user likes column as output.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT split(user_likes,"\\^")[0] as likes from user_data_consolidated
```

but the output of this query is:

```
anime^sitcom^scifi
```

Comment: It works: `hive> select split('anime^sitcom^scifi','\\^')[0];
OK
anime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT substr(user_likes,1,((locate('^',user_likes )-1)))
as likes from user_data_consolidated
```

Comment: it search for first occurrence of "^" and do a sub-string from first character to the previous char before ^